# preventing 2 error messages on jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 sets of radio buttons called 'attendance1' and 'attendace2'. When I click YES for attendance1 it asks please select attendance for USER2 and removes attendance1 for user1. How do I PREVENT THIS?

```
$(function(){   
$("#att").click(function() {
     if (!$("input[name=attendance1]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select attendance for <?php echo $row3['name1']?>');
        return false;
    }
    if (!$("input[name=attendance2]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select attendance for <?php echo $row3['name2']?>');
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Why php tag inside the alerts ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera displays name of user

Comment: Are you generating this function with php ?

Comment: Can you post the html for your inputs?

Comment: If possible please post html of your page and 2 errors you mentioned.

Comment: @SheikhHeera please see http://jsfiddle.net/NevcG/ full jquery and html. as you can see an error occurs when selecting user1 attendance but when live this will also disappear onclick on 'ok'

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. Do you have a link we can look at?

You might try changing your `if` and to `else if`:

```
$(function(){   
$("#att").click(function() {
     if (!$("input[name=attendance1]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select attendance for <?php echo $row3['name1']?>');
        return false;
    }else if (!$("input[name=attendance2]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select attendance for <?php echo $row3['name2']?>');
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: please see http://jsfiddle.net/NevcG/ full jquery and html. as you can see an error occurs when selecting user1 attendance but when live this will also disappear onclick on 'ok'

Comment: You've attached the click event to the form itself. You don't want that, you should use the `submit()` event. See http://jsfiddle.net/NevcG/6/